# Program leaks Black and White onto PowerShell console

Tags: command-line, powershell

Some programs, such as Node Package Manager (`npm`) and some tasks for `grunt` change the color of my PowerShell console and leave it that way. Here's a picture:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening? How do I get it back to normal and/or stop it from happening?

Comment: you can use the command "cls" to clear the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt the script is changing colors to bring things to your attention.  To put it back, you could use the following script.  Or better yet, add it to your profile and run 'Prompt' when you need to reset it.

```
function Prompt
{
    $promptString = "PS " + $(Get-Location) + ">"
    Write-Host $promptString -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White
    return " "
}
```